# php_gd2 is not working on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, php-gd

php_gd2 is not working on windows 8.1 every thing is ok php gd info is given below.

```
Array ( [GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible) [FreeType Support] => 1 [FreeType Linkage] => with freetype [T1Lib Support] => [GIF Read Support] => 1 [GIF Create Support] => 1 [JPEG Support] => 1 [PNG Support] => 1 [WBMP Support] => 1 [XPM Support] => 1 [XBM Support] => 1 [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => )
```

Same code is working on windows 7 but not on windows 8.1

What is error please tell me.

Comment: No you please tell us what errors you're getting. You just say 'php_gd2 is not working' but fail to say what isn't working. Where does it fail and other things like that.

Comment: image is not creating. there is no error written. sign shows there like image is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think error is in your server. because when you go from one local server to another this error occur some time and sometime not. For example when you move from wamp to xamp or xamp to wamp this error may be produced or may not. So, try by changing you local server.

Answer (score -1):

Just simple to make GD library work on Windows 8.1 x64... copy `php.ini` to `c:\windows`.